# Docker for macをKitematicや通知プラグインをインストールせずに使えますか?

Tags: docker

Docker for macでKitematicや通知プラグインをインストールせずにCUIだけで使うことはできますか?  
インストールするときに選択できるようになっているのでしょうか?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

特に選択肢なく、メニューバーアイコンが一緒にインストールされてしまいました。
ですが、イメージの作成、起動、終了、すべてCUIで操作できていますので、メニューバーアイコンはあまり気にせずCUIとして使っています。

Kitematicは、Docker for macとは別に、意図して自分でダウンロードしてきてインストールしないと入りません。

ちなみにこちらで、インストール風景やメニューバーアイコンの様子が紹介されています。
http://paiza.hatenablog.com/entry/docker_for_mac